# FormatDate(V1,S1,S2,S3)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Does anybody know where I can find a list of all the CulturueCodes ET supports for the **FormatDate(V1,S1,S2,S3)** function? The only list I could find is from the Microsoft website and I wasn't sure if all the culture codes they listed are supported by ET as well. Thanks in advance for everyone's help.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488%28v=cs.20%29.aspx

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trying all of them?

These work.  I'd include the output because SO doesn't allow some of the characters:

```
<br>af-ZA: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","af-ZA")=%%
<br>sq-AL: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","sq-AL")=%%
<br>ar-DZ: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ar-DZ")=%%
<br>ar-BH: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ar-BH")=%%
<br>ar-EG: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ar-EG")=%%
<br>ar-IQ: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ar-IQ")=%%
<br>ar-JO: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ar-JO")=%%
<br>ar-KW: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ar-KW")=%%
<br>ar-LB: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ar-LB")=%%
<br>ar-LY: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ar-LY")=%%
<br>ar-MA: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ar-MA")=%%
<br>ar-OM: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ar-OM")=%%
<br>ar-QA: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ar-QA")=%%
<br>ar-SA: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ar-SA")=%%
<br>ar-SY: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ar-SY")=%%
<br>ar-TN: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ar-TN")=%%
<br>ar-AE: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ar-AE")=%%
<br>ar-YE: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ar-YE")=%%
<br>hy-AM: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","hy-AM")=%%
<br>eu-ES : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","eu-ES")=%%
<br>be-BY : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","be-BY")=%%
<br>bg-BG : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","bg-BG")=%%
<br>ca-ES : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ca-ES")=%%
<br>zh-CN : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","zh-CN")=%%
<br>zh-HK : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","zh-HK")=%%
<br>zh-MO : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","zh-MO")=%%
<br>zh-SG : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","zh-SG")=%%
<br>zh-TW : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","zh-TW")=%%
<br>zh-CHS: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","zh-CHS")=%%
<br>zh-CHT: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","zh-CHT")=%%
<br>hr-HR : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","hr-HR")=%%
<br>cs-CZ : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","cs-CZ")=%%
<br>da-DK : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","da-DK")=%%
<br>nl-BE : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","nl-BE")=%%
<br>nl-NL : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","nl-NL")=%%
<br>en-AU : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","en-AU")=%%
<br>en-BZ : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","en-BZ")=%%
<br>en-CA : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","en-CA")=%%
<br>en-IE : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","en-IE")=%%
<br>en-JM : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","en-JM")=%%
<br>en-NZ : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","en-NZ")=%%
<br>en-PH : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","en-PH")=%%
<br>en-ZA : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","en-ZA")=%%
<br>en-TT : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","en-TT")=%%
<br>en-GB : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","en-GB")=%%
<br>en-US : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","en-US")=%%
<br>en-ZW : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","en-ZW")=%%
<br>et-EE : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","et-EE")=%%
<br>fo-FO : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","fo-FO")=%%
<br>fa-IR : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","fa-IR")=%%
<br>fi-FI : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","fi-FI")=%%
<br>fr-BE : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","fr-BE")=%%
<br>fr-CA : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","fr-CA")=%%
<br>fr-FR : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","fr-FR")=%%
<br>fr-LU : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","fr-LU")=%%
<br>fr-MC : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","fr-MC")=%%
<br>fr-CH : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","fr-CH")=%%
<br>gl-ES : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","gl-ES")=%%
<br>ka-GE : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ka-GE")=%%
<br>de-AT : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","de-AT")=%%
<br>de-DE : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","de-DE")=%%
<br>de-LI : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","de-LI")=%%
<br>de-LU : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","de-LU")=%%
<br>de-CH : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","de-CH")=%%
<br>el-GR : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","el-GR")=%%
<br>gu-IN : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","gu-IN")=%%
<br>he-IL : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","he-IL")=%%
<br>hi-IN : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","hi-IN")=%%
<br>hu-HU : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","hu-HU")=%%
<br>is-IS : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","is-IS")=%%
<br>id-ID : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","id-ID")=%%
<br>it-IT : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","it-IT")=%%
<br>it-CH : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","it-CH")=%%
<br>ja-JP : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ja-JP")=%%
<br>kn-IN : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","kn-IN")=%%
<br>kk-KZ : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","kk-KZ")=%%
<br>kok-IN: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","kok-IN")=%%
<br>ko-KR : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ko-KR")=%%
<br>lv-LV : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","lv-LV")=%%
<br>lt-LT : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","lt-LT")=%%
<br>mk-MK : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","mk-MK")=%%
<br>ms-BN : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ms-BN")=%%
<br>ms-MY : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ms-MY")=%%
<br>mr-IN : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","mr-IN")=%%
<br>mn-MN : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","mn-MN")=%%
<br>nb-NO : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","nb-NO")=%%
<br>nn-NO : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","nn-NO")=%%
<br>pl-PL : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","pl-PL")=%%
<br>pt-BR : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","pt-BR")=%%
<br>pt-PT : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","pt-PT")=%%
<br>pa-IN : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","pa-IN")=%%
<br>ro-RO : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ro-RO")=%%
<br>ru-RU : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ru-RU")=%%
<br>sa-IN : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","sa-IN")=%%
<br>sk-SK: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","sk-SK")=%%
<br>sl-SI: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","sl-SI")=%%
<br>es-AR: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-AR")=%%
<br>es-BO: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-BO")=%%
<br>es-CL: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-CL")=%%
<br>es-CO: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-CO")=%%
<br>es-CR: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-CR")=%%
<br>es-DO: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-DO")=%%
<br>es-EC: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-EC")=%%
<br>es-SV: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-SV")=%%
<br>es-GT: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-GT")=%%
<br>es-HN: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-HN")=%%
<br>es-MX: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-MX")=%%
<br>es-NI: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-NI")=%%
<br>es-PA: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-PA")=%%
<br>es-PY: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-PY")=%%
<br>es-PE: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-PE")=%%
<br>es-PR: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-PR")=%%
<br>es-ES: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-ES")=%%
<br>es-UY: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-UY")=%%
<br>es-VE: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","es-VE")=%%
<br>sw-KE: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","sw-KE")=%%
<br>sv-FI: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","sv-FI")=%%
<br>sv-SE: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","sv-SE")=%%
<br>syr-SY: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","syr-SY")=%%
<br>ta-IN : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ta-IN")=%%
<br>tt-RU : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","tt-RU")=%%
<br>te-IN : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","te-IN")=%%
<br>th-TH : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","th-TH")=%%
<br>tr-TR : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","tr-TR")=%%
<br>uk-UA : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","uk-UA")=%%
<br>ur-PK : %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","ur-PK")=%%
<br>vi-VN: %%=FormatDate(now(),"MMM DD, YYYY","HH:MM:SS.MMM","vi-VN")=%%
```

These don't:

```
ky-KZ
en-CB
div-MV
Cy-az-AZ
Lt-az-AZ
Cy-sr-SP
Lt-sr-SP
Cy-uz-UZ
Lt-uz-UZ
```

Comment: oh man this is great!!! Thank you for finding all these culture codes. What website did you reference for all these? That way I can bookmark it for later. Thanks again Adam.

Comment: I used the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488%28v=cs.20%29.aspx) link you referenced.

Comment: Ahh ok, I thought you might have pulled those from somewhere on the ET documentation site. Thanks for testing all these, it helps.

Comment: Aside from the interface timezone handling for user accounts and automations, localization is tough in the SFMC platform.  Here's the [wiki page](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/international_sends/) that describes the base support.